# C# Explanation of stream string example

Tags: c#, streaming, bit-manipulation

I am using a Microsoft example for interprocess communication.  In the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-use-named-pipes-for-network-interprocess-communication) there are two methods for reading/writing a string to/from a stream.  The code sends the length of the string being streamed in the data.  I need similar code, but need to make some modifications.  An explanation of the highlighted lines would be helpful.

In `WriteString()`, they taken the length of the byte array being written and divide it by 256.  The opposite is done in `ReadString()`, but an explanation as to why `256` is used would be great.  Then, it writes another byte by taking the length and `&` it with 255.  I don't understand the reasoning for this either.  I'm thinking it shifts the value, but I don't really understand why this is needed.  And then in `ReadString()` it does a `+=` to the length by reading a byte.  An explanation of this would be really helpful.  I'm new to streaming and just want to understand exactly what is happening and why.

```
    public string ReadString()
{
    int len = 0;

    // the next two lines
    len = ioStream.ReadByte() * 256;
    len += ioStream.ReadByte();
    byte[] inBuffer = new byte[len];
    ioStream.Read(inBuffer, 0, len);

    return streamEncoding.GetString(inBuffer);
}

public int WriteString(string outString)
{
    byte[] outBuffer = streamEncoding.GetBytes(outString);
    int len = outBuffer.Length;
    if (len > UInt16.MaxValue)
    {
        len = (int)UInt16.MaxValue;
    }

    // the next to lines
    ioStream.WriteByte((byte)(len / 256));
    ioStream.WriteByte((byte)(len & 255));
    ioStream.Write(outBuffer, 0, len);
    ioStream.Flush();

    return outBuffer.Length + 2;
}
```

Comment: They are splitting the length in 2 bytes. Dividing by 256 and oring with 255 is making sure you only get the bits you need. If your integer is like this: byte3 byte2 byte1 byte0 then len / 256 (and converted to byte) gets byte1 and & 255 gets byte0. In essence `len` is truncated to a `short`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is bad, find a new tutorial.

The 256 stuff is there to convert the low 2 bytes of the length integer to bytes in order to serialize/deserialize them. This is not how it's normally done. Use `BinaryReader/Writer` or code not based on multiplication but on binary and and shift.

Dividing by 256 is equivalent to `x >> 8`. Also this only works with positive integers. `x & 255` is used to take the lowest byte. This could simply be `(byte)x`. Sometimes people write `x % 256` for this which not idiomatic and has problems with signedness.

Good code would be `new byte[] { (byte)(x >> 8), (byte)(x >> 0) }` and `x = bytes[1] << 8 | bytes[0]`. Much simpler, faster and idiomatic. I like writing `>> 0` which does nothing for the sake of symmetry. It's optimized away. This might seem ridiculous for 16 bit ints but with longer ints there are 4 or 8 components and having one of them slightly off seems like needless inconsistency.

```
ioStream.Read(inBuffer, 0, len);
```

is a bug because it assumes the read completes in one chunk. Need a loop or again `BinaryReader`.

```
if (len > UInt16.MaxValue)
{
    len = (int)UInt16.MaxValue;
}
```

---

I'm going to use this opportunity to warn anyone who reads this: Microsoft .NET sample code often is of extremely poor quality. Read it with great skepticism.

Comment: They also assume that len <= short.MaxValue which could also mangle your string if it uses multibytes

Comment: @Neijwiert I don't believe they do. They truncate the string in that case. I think the dirty division stuff works with ushort.MaxValue but I'm not sure.

Comment: I'm not seeing where the string is truncated. But I edited the first comment that if multibyte chars are used it could mangle the result string by cutting off bytes mid character

Comment: It is truncated by clipping len and writing len bytes. You are right about the multibyte issue.

Comment: sorry, I thought you meant truncated as in before it is passed to `WriteString`

Comment: @usr just wondering, in java, where I came from, you can declare 255 as `0b1111_1111` for example making this a far more readable way. Do you have such a thing?

Comment: @Eugene this is in C# now I believe. It is a very recent addition. I personally dislike this for this purpose. Imagine a 64 bit binary constant... I like to use the `uint.MaxValue` etc. constants best, 2nd would be 0xFF because it's shorter yet you can immediately see all the ones in the F letter. Maybe this is just subjective taste formed by my programming experiences. Some people like using `-1` which I personally dislike.

Comment: @usr no no, quite a lot agree with you. `0xFF` is the way, I was just wondering here